# real time monitoring dashboard for iot devices using aws

Tags: amazon-web-services

I want to create a real-time monitoring system for my IOT devices with some analytical functions using AWS services. So far, I have been successful in getting the data using AWS IOT Core and stored it to Dynamo DB. But I am stuck on taking out the average of the available data, I need to take out the average of incoming data every 15 mins. (For

Example: Considering the data logged from 00:00:00 to 00:15:00, I need to take out the average of the data logged in those 15 mins and so on).

How can I carry out such analytical function, which service will enable me to do this kind of operations (AWS Analytics, Lambda, Kinesis, or any other service)? Also, once this is done, I must show this data on a dashboard to specific users based on their device (For example: If I have a fleet of 100 IOT devices, and it belongs to 5 different people having an equal share of devices, each user can monitor data from his share of 20 devices only when he logs in to the system).

Kindly help me find the best possible solution for implementing this problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a script to run in lambda, which inturn is triggered by stepfunction or cloudwatch at a interval of 15 min (or as you desire).Then, use this lambda to scan or query through the dynamodb to update required info. For analytical view, you can use aws quicksight dashboard.

Answer (score 0):

If you are storing data in DynamoDB, the best measure is to use a DynamoDB streams attached to a Lambda function.

The lambda can be invoked at times to insert a count record if within a block of time you desire.

Then the count records can be divided by the block time to get the average.

This is efficient given that all the records stored are not changed after storage.